# Transform JSON to XLS file with Python

Tags: python, json, xlsx

**I'm trying to transform a JSON file to a XLS file, but it returns me an error called:**

**-> name = record['name']
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str**

I've already tried do that thing with JS but I'm completely lost, I think Python Will be more easy to understand all of this

```
import os
import json
import win32com.client as win32  # pip install pywin32
import requests
"""
Step 1.1 Read the JSON file
"""


json_data = requests.get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
print(json_data.content)

"""
Step 1.2 Examing the data and flatten the records into a 2D layout
"""
rows = []

for record in json_data:
    name = record['name']


"""
Step 2. Inserting Records to an Excel Spreadsheet
"""
ExcelApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
ExcelApp.Visible = True

wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

header_labels = ('name')

# insert header labels
for indx, val in enumerate(header_labels):
    ws.Cells(1, indx + 1).Value = val

# insert Records
row_tracker = 2
column_size = len(header_labels)

for row in rows:
    ws.Range(
        ws.Cells(row_tracker, 1),
        ws.Cells(row_tracker, column_size)
    ).value = row
    row_tracker += 1

wb.SaveAs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Json output.xlsx'), 51)
wb.Close()
ExcelApp.Quit()
ExcelApp = None
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: if server sends JSON data then you should get `json_data.json()` or `json.loads(json_data.content)` to get it as dictionary because `json_data.content` has it as bytes

Comment: you have empty `rows` because you forgot `row.append(name)` inside `for`-loop

Answer (score 1):

`.content` gives data as `bytes`. You should get `.json()` to have it as Python dictionary.

```
response = requests.get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")

json_data = response.json()

#json_data = json.loads(response.content)
```

---

Minimal working example

I use `[:10]` only to display first 10 values but you should skip `[:10]`

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")

json_data = response.json()
#print(json_data)

rows = []

for record in json_data[:10]:
    name = record['name']['official']
    print(name)
    rows.append(name)
```

Result:

```
Republic of Finland
Republic of Guatemala
Republic of Chile
Oriental Republic of Uruguay
Kyrgyz Republic
Republic of Zambia
Niue
Republic of Austria
Georgia
Republic of Trinidad and Tobago
```